# How do I rename the **entire** path

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management, path, rename, batch-rename

I need to rename (in particular not to copy nor to move) in `Windows 8.1` this file path

```
D:\Users\hynek0\1703.08094.pdf – zástupce
```

to this path

```
C:\Users\hynek0\1703.08094.pdf – zástupce
```

Here,  `– zástupce` is the Czech word for reference (.lnk) file.

Note the different disks `D:\` and `C:\` here.

But **I do know** how to rename this if it is on the same disk and directory:

```
C:\Users\a.pdf
```

to

```
C:\Users\b.pdf
```

---

Also and more generally I would like to rename **all files**

```
D:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf – zástupce
```

to

```
C:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf – zástupce
```

---

And finally without  `– zástupce`:

```
D:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf
```

to

```
C:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding what Rename actually means.

Rename means changing the name or extension of a certain file or folder. What you trying to do is a move operation.

You have to first copy the PDF file to the same folder on D drive to C drive. Then you have to delete the file in D drive. Then the PDF will exist in the folder on C drive.

Like this you can use a Batch script for moving all PDF files:

```
@echo off
cd "Source path"
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
  move "%%~fa" "Destination path\"
)
exit /b 0
```

Comment: OK. Is this line correct: `%%~fa` ? Shouldn't it be `%%~a` without f before a ? And what about \" : is this \ the only correct slash, isn't it odd and in fact should there be 2 such \ ?

Comment: This looks correct to me. In CMD \ is not used to escape. ITs actually part of the path. To escape a ", you write "". %%~fa also looks correct to me. Have you even tried it or just said... hmm, looks incorrect, so it must be wrong?

Comment: @LPChip Yes, I've just said "hmm, looks incorrect, so it must be wrong" because the data is critical to me so I'm careful. Anyway, why is % there twice in the `for loop` and what does `%%~fa` mean ?

Comment: Make a copy of your data before you execute the command, so you can always restore it. %% is required when this runs inside a batchfile and %%~fa is a special modifier to extract information from the variable. See for /? for more info

Comment: %%~fa expands to the full path of the file, this is for extra security. And \ is not for escaping, ^ is the escaping sign in batch, and it indicates a directory in path.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove unwanted strings?

```bat
Ren "C:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf – z?stupce.lnk" "*.pdf.lnk"

:: or, without/removing .lnk ::

Ren "C:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf – z?stupce.lnk" "*.pdf"
```

Or, copying renaming this files:

```bat
copy "D:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf – zástupce.lnk" "C:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf.lnk"

rem :: or, wit removing .lnk ::

copy "D:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf – zástupce.lnk" "C:\Users\hynek0\*.pdf"
```

You also can use substring:

```bat
rem :: string: .pdf – zástupce.lnk
rem ::         |||||||||||||||||||
rem :: length: 1234567890123456789 == 19 

rem :: recursive loop rename and removing the last 19 characters: "%_name:~0,-19%.lnk"
for /r "C:\Users\hynek0" %i in (*.lnk)do set "_name=%~nxi" && @call ren "%~i" "%_name:~0,-19%.lnk"

rem :: rename removing the last 19 characters: "%_name:~0,-19%.lnk"
```

Some further reading:

- [`Copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)
- [`ren` | `rename`](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)
- [Why does `call set` work differently [refer: `call ren`]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893287/why-does-call-set-work-differently-in-a-cmd-windows-versus-a-cmd-file)

Comment: It works. But why the help to `Ren` writes this: `Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file` on the contrary what your last example says?

Comment: ren sintaxe: **`ren full_file_path_name_ext new name.ext`** cannot be possible to change the drive\folder...